# Optimus/Nvidia and OpengGL giving troubles

Tags: drivers, graphics, bumblebee, opengl

First time writing on this forum so be nice :D
I am a programmer but I mostly worked on windows so far , I wanted to 
start learning linux more seriously and being able to compile my cpp programs
on ubuntu 12.04 aswell.
What I am interested in doing at the moment is some Opengl programs. now here the troubles starts.
I tried to compile a simple freeglut window and everything works , bot normal and optirun way. Now I sucessifully compiled glfw3 and compiled a test program.
If I run normaly (without the optirun ) , the program works and show up on screen properly
but shoots out this warning :
Xlib:  extension "NV-GLX" missing on display ":0".

Which still I dunno how bad it is.
If then I run optirun version I get some nice errors  here is the log :

```
###########################################
giordi@giordi-linux-pc:/usr/local/src/glfw-3.0.4$ optirun ./main.exec 
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: Try again with LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose for more details.
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
libGL error: Try again with LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose for more details.
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: Try again with LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose for more details.
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
libGL error: Try again with LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose for more details.
primus: fatal: failed to acquire direct rendering context for display thread
################################################
```

I googled around and looks like I am missing some kind of 32 bit drivers??
I installed the nividia drivers as explained here :
http://www.muktware.com/2013/12/install-nvidia-331-bumblebee-optimus-cards/18271

Anyone can spread a litght please?
I did the same kind of setup on an old laptop of mine and everything works fine , except for the fact is running drivers version 319.
I can rpogram on the old laptop of course but on my current laptop I am running a GTX 780M and I wish to use that for high performance graphic and computing.

Any help much appreciated

Cheers

M.

Comment: I got it working somehow.
What I did was clean re-instal,then not use bumblebee, I used official prime solution (nvidia-prime).
Only slight issue was to make  it working on 12.04 we need to use backports which install specific version of packages like  xorg-dev , which needs to be xorg-dev-lts-raring , so be carefull when you install Opengl or similar dependencies.
Took me quite a while of test to make it run because when I was installing dependecies of glfw  I was installing regular xorg-dev which was removing many *-lts-raring and reinstalling many -saucy and so on.
Hope it helps!

cheers

Comment: I'm having a similar "failed to acquire direct rendering context" problem, too; see [this](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/slackware-current-kernel-3-14-16-and-nvidia-optimus-4175514098/#post5224966).

Comment: Dec. 14, 2014, patch pertaining to the "failed to acquire direct rendering context" issue: http://pastebin.com/fJTtpHGU